# Difference using localhost, 127.0.0.1, computer name and static ip

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sqlclr

I want to consume a web service that is running on the local machine (don't ask me why, I didn't make the web service, just need to use it), and I want to know if there is any difference (technical and maybe performance) by referencing it via localhost, 127.0.0.1, the computer name and the computer static IP? This is critical, because I need to consume the web service almost each 30 seconds from a table trigger inside a database (again, don't ask me why, it's all I can do in this case). The web service has been written in ASP.NET, and the object which access it from the database is a CLR user defined function made in C#.NET

EDIT: I'm sorry, 30 seconds was a poor estimate. It's a transactional table where the sales of almost one hundred stores are saved on-line. The period it's variable, from several minutes to milliseconds between transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where the web service is exposed (listening on).

`localhost` and `127.0.0.1` will contact it on the internal localhost interface. The other two  methods will look for the service on a particular network card.

From performance perspective, using an IP address is a little bit faster as it avoids a DNS lookup which would however in this case be resolved locally and be pretty much instantaneous as well.  (30 seconds is a relative infinity so this cannot be a bottleneck.)

From maintenance perspective, the static IP address is most likely to bite you.

Winner: `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

Answer (score 3):

30 seconds is really a long time compared to "real time" so the IP you use will make no difference and will be transparent to your application.

Comment: I'm sorry. It was a poor estimate. It's a real time transactional table, where the sales from almost one hundred stores are saved on-line.

Answer (score 1):

No real performance impact but the quickest ones should be the 127.0.0.1 and the static IP since there is no lookup to be done in the hosts files or on the DNS. And since you have a window of 30 seconds it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference.

Whilst all four authority names will cause a TCP connection to be made to the same host the difference is in HTTP: HTTP has the "Host:" header which the browser or client sends and the content of this header is the hostname part of the URI authority name.

The Host header is important because it's how webservers like IIS route requests to the right website even when multiple websites share an IP address (HTTP1.1 has the Host header, HTTP1.0 did not, so back in the mid-1990s each website needed its own IP address).

If your web-service runs on a server that uses the Host header, or if it uses the Host header itself, then it does matter.

Performance-wise the difference is negligible since "localhost" and "%computername%" should be permanently stored in your DNS client's cache, but it's common-sense to avoid hardcoding hostnames in your application.

Comment: So do you mean I have to specify a hostname if the web service has one assigned to it?

Comment: Yes. If your webservice is configured to only respond to "localhost" then connecting to http://127.0.0.1 won't work because the Host header will be set to "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost".

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference, however they will all translate into 127.0.0.1 so you may as well provide this first.

If you check out your hosts file you can see that localhost is directly translating into 127.0.0.1